# Using "autoLink" in android make the whole text click able, how to avoid that?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making a text view in which I am `pro-grammatically` setting the support email and the site link of my website, its working fine but the problem is that the whole simple text which is not email or the link is `clickable`. When i click the screen the colour changes, I want to disable that can anyone please help.

I have tried :

```
1) clickable = false 

2) longclick = false

3) focusable = false
```

but to no avail, if anyone knows the solution kindly let me know. Thanks a lot.

```
 <TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:clickable="false"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:autoLink="web|email"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: Remove the autolink attribute then. AutoLink makes the view clickable

Comment: Android L i need that bcz i want to open the web browser page

Comment: Which color changes ? simply define a click listener for it and write the intent code for opening a web page

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Pkmmte no I haven't

Comment: It seems like crappy design by google.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: I have tried this it won't help, any ways thanks a lot.

Comment: this actually works for another case - when you want the link inside the text to be clickable, AND the rest of text itself to be clickable for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
```

but try to avoid using "autoLink" when using this method. I've read somewhere they don't get along with each other.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through Android's source code for a few hours, I finally found a solution for this.

By default, LinkMovementMethod consumes all touch events for the view, so all we basically need to do is subclass it and override that behavior:

```java
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created on 2/17/2017
 *
 * @author Pkmmte Xeleon
 */
public class PkMovementMethod extends LinkMovementMethod {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += widget.getScrollX();
            y += widget.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off + 1, ClickableSpan.class);

            if (link.length != 0) {
                link[0].onClick(widget);
                return true;
            } else {
                Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You'll need to disable clicks after setting this MovementMethod:

```java
myTextView.setMovementMethod(new PkMovementMethod());
myTextView.setClickable(false);
myTextView.setLongClickable(false);
```

You can find my gist for it here:
https://gist.github.com/Pkmmte/ea3dfd384cddc687d506faaee88f191d

Comment: The only downside to this solution is that click events will be called when you touch down, not up. A fix for this would require delegating to a parent view first.